# How can I get the rendered output of a View as a string with the javascript executed

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.Net MVC5.
I need to create a PDF of a View which contains a c3.js chart.

As the chart is rendered an created through javascript (it creates an svg).

I tried to get the View output mentioned in:
[Render a view as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string)

But I just get the initial HTML of the View with the CSS styling.
I need the javascript to be executed before creating the PDF.

Please let me know if anybody has faced such a situation.

Or it also would be helpful to suggest any javascript library where I can get a specific  as a pdf (without a server trip).

Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think that's possible.  The browser executes your javascript and the browser is the bit you're bypassing by rendering to a string.

You could maybe put a button on your generated (rendered as a View) view offering a PDF and create the PDF as described here? - http://www.techumber.com/2015/04/html-to-pdf-conversion-using-javascript.html

Comment: @RichBryant Thanks for the response buddy... I have a doubt though... For the CSS also its the browser who applies the styles, how come that part works here? Also, I will sure give a try to your suggestion. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Granted, but your javascript is usually triggered on document.ready and when rendered to a string, that event doesn't occur.

Comment: @RichBryant Thanks, I tried your solution, but that didn't fit much in my environment... However I found another workaround and used the .Net chart library for generating the chart, which can generate an image which is then included in the View using an <img>.